# Why Is a Fiber A Vector Space

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles

I'm trying to learn about vector bundles in the context of differentiable manifolds and have a very basic question which most introductions to the topic seem to consider obvious.  Let $M$ be a manifold and let $E=M\times \mathbb{R}^n$ be the total space.  Let $p:E\to M$ be the projection.  My question is, for $x\in M$ why is $p^{-1}(x)\subset E$ a vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $p^{-1}(x)$ is just $\{x\}\times\mathbb{R}^n$.  This has a canonical vector space structure by using the standard vector space structure on the second coordinate.  That is, define addition and scalar multiplication by $(x,v)+(x,w)=(x,v+w)$ and $\lambda\cdot (x,v)=(x,\lambda v)$.

Comment: Thanks!  It's always obvious after someone explains it =p